# change display order(number) in django admin easier?

Tags: django, admin, django-suit

Currently, I add `display_order` to my models, and my model objects will be display in `main.html` order_by this number.

i.e. I when I have 5 objects, I can give numbers to them 1 to 5, and it's displayed in main page from 1 to 5.

like this

[image]

Unfortunately, it's little bit hard to change numbers one by one every time change this order. So I want to change this method for admin people.

Is there more convenient way to change those order at one, more easily?

Any suggestions and ideas are fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I can give numbers to them 1 to 5* | which field that you gave these values?

Comment: I give like `main_order`, positiveintegerfield.